# Check if a value exists in Column Mysqli php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I developing a chat app, in that i need to connect between two users in my database and the **point** is i dont want to connect users that already connected earlier. So i store a column to store the already connected users which will be in the format: `id1|id2|id3|.....|id50`.

First i thought of selecting a user and get his id and then fetch the user's connected column and then by **php** check if id exists in his column, thus denying that chat. But it makes lot more complicated.

Can anyone recommend a strategy to make this simple by using only `MySQL Queries`, i am not advanced in writing nested or join queries and the don't know all pre-defined functions that exist in MySQL.

Can anyone make a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN (this,that,these,those,em)

if statement returns not empty value, sure, user exists.

I wrote example where you can check many users at once. Just implode your id-user-list and quire em in parenthesise..

Thus, u'll need to parse returned array to see who succeeded in selecting, who not. (compare two arrays)

Happy coding..